# SQL COALESCE return more that 1 value or alternate solution

Tags: sql-server

Post has been revised!!!....

I need help on the WHERE condition as the following:

ID# 1 belongs to Engineering Department.

ID# 2 belongs to Sales Department

ID# 3 belongs to Other Department.

ID# 4 belongs to Eng-Level2 department

ID# 5 belongs to Eng-Level3 department

ID# 6 belongs to Eng-Level4 department

What I try to accomplish is, if ID# 1 log run this report, it will show the activities belong to him (ID# 1), AND Eng-Levelx (ID#4, ID#5, and ID#6).  However, if ID belongs to another Departments (ID# 2 & 3), will ONLY show the activities below to his/her.

Here is my non working query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.CRM_Activity
WHERE 
(ActivityOwnerID = 1579
AND [Status] = 'Open'
AND Status <> 'Deleted')
OR
    ActivityOwnerID IN (
        SELECT COALESCE(
            (SELECT Tech_ID FROM dbo.employee WHERE tech_ID = 1579 and POSITION = 'Engineering')
            ,  (SELECT Tech_ID FROM dbo.employee WHERE LEFT(first_name, 4) = 'Eng-')  --- THIS ONE FAILED BECAUSE IT RETURNS MULTIPLE RECORDS
        )
    )
    AND [Status] = 'Open'

ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `UNION` instead, so this will get a list of unique `Tech_ID`'s from both queries.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.CRM_Activity
WHERE 
    ActivityOwnerID IN (

            SELECT Tech_ID FROM dbo.employee WHERE tech_ID = 1579 and POSITION = 'Engineering'
            UNION
            SELECT Tech_ID FROM dbo.employee WHERE LEFT(first_name, 4) = 'Eng-'
        )
```

Comment: @christiandev, thank you for responding, it is not the results I am hoping to get. I am revising the questions now to be more clear.... my apologize!

Comment: I revised the post, please see if you can help.  Thank you!

Comment: @milacay I suspect it should  be `LEFT(position, 4) = 'Eng-'` not `LEFT(first_name)`

Comment: I used "EXISTS" and it works now.  thanks all for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `SELECT COALESCE(....` can return more than one value because `IN` allows multiple values, but result of `SELECT Tech_ID FROM dbo.employee WHERE tech_ID = 1579 and POSITION = 'Engineering'` or so must be one because `COALESCE` expects expression (not result set).